# Moving MySQL from localhost to remote server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I’ve just finished writing a website which is working very well on my local server (xampp).
The following is my connection database definitions for the local server:

```
<?php
  $host="localhost";
  $username="root";
  $password="1234";
  $db_name="partnership";

  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
?>
```

I’ve loaded my files successfully and put them on the remote server (www.mydomain.com) and I’ve created the relevant database ‘partnership’ (successfully imported all Tables from phpMySQL local server to the remote server).

I can view the website  (www.mydomain.com) but with no connection to the database (MySQL).
The error message is of course "cannot connect".

I’ve changed `$host="localhost"` to `$host=”www.mydomain.com”` but still getting the same error message.

Any assistance on the above issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a hosting provider, or is this a server under your control?

Comment: created db, but how about users and permission

Comment: I have a hosting account from a web host services company.

Comment: Check out [this response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2768938/264628) from a similar question. I've found the fourth option is usually relevant on Windows.

Comment: Check your account control panel to ensure you know what host name you should be using. For example, it could be your domain, or mysql.(your domain), or something else entirely.

Comment: Hardest part about these types of issues is that the answer isn't obvious. It will require some debugging on your part. For example: Is the host name correct? Is the username/password correct? Are the permissions set correctly? Try running mysql_error() after attempting to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using cPanel, when you create the MySQL table, make sure you assign your user to it (trivial, I know, but Ive forgotten about it a few times myself.)

If your script is running from your remote server, just stick with localhost. Will work fine.

Last, my only suggestion until a better answer is said, try using

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'username'; // Im pretty sure your username isn't root.
$pass = '1234';
$db = 'partnership'; 
/* Alot of hosts like to append your cPanel login to your db and username fields.
Check to see what your table is. It might actually be 'youruser_partnership'  */

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user , $pass, $db);
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

If your host supports mysqli (most do). If not, when you do your die statement, still use `die(mysql_error());` to get the exact error. It will more than likely be your username/password you created and assigned to your database

Comment: Thank you all for replying to me, and thanks for the above comment which solved the problem (“Alot of hosts like to append your cPanel login to your db and username fields.” ). These are the changes which made now successful connection to DB:

$user = 'mydomai_username';

$db = 'mydomai_partnership';

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you still use `localhost` as `$host` if you're trying to connect via the application? The script is on the same server as the DB.

Comment: This is what I’m not sure about. i.e. what/how to define $host (host name).

Comment: @user try defining it as `'127.0.0.1'`.  `'localhost'` doesn't always work for some reason.

Comment: @user1315169: If you're using PHPMyAdmin it can tell you. Otherwise just look in your hosting's administration panel, it should tell you where the database is hosted.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, this is always the most annoying part of the process.  Try this and see if it works:

```
$host="127.0.0.1";  // "localhost" should work, but don't count on it
$username="user"; // username you use to log into phpMyAdmin
$password="password"; // password you use to log into phpMyAdmin
$db_name="dbname"; // database you want to connect to
```

You'll need to have created this user/password pair and given them the appropriate permissions to access the database.  Also note that the mysql PHP functions are deprecated and should not be used.  PDO or mysqli are the preferred ones going forward.

Comment: phpMyAdmin on my local server always ask for login (username and password).
On my remote server I get access to the DB without the “Welcome to phpMyAdmin” screen. (no login process to enter the DB, although I’ve created  username and password).
Is it related anyhow to the connection problem which described above?