# Fix: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: php

I am having this problem when I am trying to run my simple file on Php. I am using xampp on Windows 7.

This is my code:

```
 <?php
 $dbName = "users";
 $dbUsername = "****";
 $dbPassword = "";
 $dbServer = "localhost";
 mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUsername, $dbPassword,$dbName);
 enter code here?>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Most probably, your DB credentials are wrong.

Comment: Try the answers posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768916/trouble-connecting-to-mysql-db-php)

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger. Thanks it solved my problem, but I got a new problem. This is what I get. `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`

Answer (score 0):

you can use $mysqli->error() / mysqli_error() to get the error description.
Like:

```
<?php
mysqli_connect($dbServer, $dbUsername, $dbPassword,$dbName);
var_dump( mysqli_error() );die;
```